# bigquery select all columns that contain string

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How to select all columns with that contain a string? Either prefix, suffix or containing.

Column names
**Available columns** : a_test, b_test, c_test, d_test, e, f, g, test_h, test_i
**Selected Prefix columns** : a_test, b_test, c_test, d_test
**Selected Suffix columns** : test_h, test_i
**Selected all test columns** : a_test, b_test, c_test, d_test, test_h, test_i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only want to search in tables, start with this:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
WHERE (C.COLUMN_NAME LIKE @prefix + '_' + 'test' 
       OR C.COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'test' + '_' + @suffix )
AND C.TABLE_NAME = 'MYTABLENAME'
```

...and change the "WHERE" condition according to your needs.

Edited: no INNER JOIN and changed where condition.

Comment: Hi @Ricardo, I only want to select columns from a single table with data associated. Thus, a quicker way of naming the columns required(in a select statement) if they columns contain a similiar prefix.